# Safest way to implement multiple timers inside a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

As the title says, I'm looking for the best way to implement multiple timers in C++ (not c++ 11).
My idea is having a single pthread (posix) to handle timers.
I need at least 4 timers, 3 periodic and 1 single shot.
The minimum resolution should be 1 second (for the shortest timer) and 15 hours for the longest one.
All the timers should be running at the same time.

These are the different implementations that come to my mind (I don't know if they are the safest in a thread environment or the easiest ones):

1) Using itimerspec, sigaction and sigevent structure like this:

```
static int Tcreate( char *name, timer_t *timerID, int expireMS, int intervalMS )
{
   struct sigevent         te;
   struct itimerspec       its;
   struct sigaction        sa;
   int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sa.sa_sigaction = app;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
   {
       perror("sigaction");
   }

   /* Set and enable alarm */
   te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
   te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
   timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

   its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
   its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
   its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
   its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
   timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

   return 1;
}
```

2) Using clock() and checking for time difference, like this:

```
std::clock_t start;
double duration;
start = std::clock();
duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

3) Using chrono like this:

```
auto diff = tp - chrono::system_clock::time_point();
  cout << "diff:" << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::minutes>(diff).count()
       << " minute(s)" << endl;
  Days days = chrono::duration_cast<Days>(diff);
  cout << "diff:" << days.count() << " day(s)" << endl;
```

Please, consider these as ideas, not actual working code.

What is your opinion about it ?

Comment: Option #3 is C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the head up. I supposed to be C++ 11, checked on C++ reference site right now. If you could possibly suggest other methods it would greately help me. I don't need of course the complete code, just an idea of implementation.

Comment: You can compute next expiration delay and use select/poll/epoll system calls (using the timeout). Or sleep/clock_nanosleep. Either way, you'll need to check time when waking up as those can return early. Good thing with select/poll/epoll method is it integrates well in an event loop, you don't even need a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your timer thread is responsible *only* for the timers, and the minimum resolution is 1 second, and the timing doesn't need to be that precise (i.e. if +/- 0.1 second is good enough), then a simple implementation for the timer thread is to just sleep for 1 second, check for any timers that need to fire, and repeat, as in the following psuedocode:

```
repeat:
  sleep 1
  t = t+1
  for timer in timers where timer(t) = true:
    fire(timer)
```

The hard part will be populating the structure that stores the timers - presumably timers will be set by other threads, possibly by multiple threads that could try to set timers simultaneously.  It would be advisable to use some standard data structure like a thread-safe queue to pass messages to the timer thread, which on each cycle would then update the collection of timers itself:

```
repeat:
  sleep 1
  t = t+1
  while new_timer_spec = pop(timer_queue):
    add_timer(new_timer_spec)
  for timer in timers where timer(t) = true:
    fire(timer)
```

Another thing to consider is the nature of `fire(timer)` - what to do here really depends on the needs of the threads that use the timers.  Perhaps just setting a variable that they could read would be sufficient, or maybe this could fire a signal that threads could listen for.

Comment: I will use an event handler both to set the timer and to receive the fire(timer) so I won't have multiple threads trying to set it at once. Many thanks for your idea !

Comment: actually, in such approach you dont need any timer, you could just maintain a counter as a timer and decrement this counter everytime the thread wakes up. If the counter is 0, then the timer has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Since all your timer creation apparently goes through a single API (i.e., the controlling code has visibility into all timers), you can avoid signals or busy-looping entirely and keep a sorted list of timers (like a `std::map` keyed by deadline), and simply wait on a condition variable using (for example) [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html). The condition variable mutex protects the list of timers.

If you schedule a new timer whose deadline is earlier than the current "next" timer, you'll need to wake the sleeping thread and schedule an adjusted sleep (if it wasn't for this requirement you could use plain `usleep` or whatever). This all happens inside the mutex associated with the condition variable.

You don't have to use condition variables, but they seem the cleanest, since the associated mutex is naturally used to protect the list of timers. You could probably also build this on top of a semaphone with `sem_timedwait`, but or on top of `select` on an internal socket, pipe or something like that, but then you're stuck separately controlling multi-threaded access to the timer queue.

Comment: Do you mean something like this ?                   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now)
reltime = sleep_til_this_absolute_time -now;
cond_relative_timed_wait(c, m, &reltime);                                              But while waiting the thread will hold the mutex, right ? What will happen then to other threads waiting to acquire it ? Maybe I misunderstood how a pthread_cond_timedwait works. Could you possibly confirm, please ?

Comment: @Podarce - the way condition variables work is that the mutex is released when you `wait()` on them. In particular, you'd use the mutex to protect the structure that has the sorted list of timers. Anyone adding a timer would take the mutex, add the timer, and check if the wait time needs to be adjusted, and then leave the mutex.